# standard deviation of piecewise function

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

Let $X$ be a random variable, with probability density function

$f(x)=
\begin{array}{cc}
  \{ & 
    \begin{array}{cc}
      \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2) & -1\leq x\leq 1 \\
      0 & \text{otherwise}
    \end{array}
\end{array}
$

What is the standard deviation of $X$? I only know how to find standard deviation of set of point, how do I find it of a function? I am preparing for the GRE subject and have not taken probability before. The answer is $\frac{\sqrt{5}}{5}$. Is it just $x$ times the function integrated from $-1$ to $1$?

Comment: This can be found in any introductory book on probability theory. For example this: https://www.probabilitycourse.com/chapter4/4_1_1_pdf.php

Comment: No, this is the expected value only.  The variance is $Var(X)=\int_{-1}^1 x^2\cdot \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2) \, dx-\left[ \int_{-1}^1 x\cdot \frac{3}{4}(1-x^2) \, dx\right]^2$, which is $Var(X)=\mathbb E(X^2)-[\mathbb E(X)]^2$ To get the standard deviation take the square root.

Comment: @callculus42 the square root of that entire thing, correct?

Comment: thanks! @callculus42 I got the correct answer, btw the latter of the two integrals is identically zero as it is odd , correct?

Comment: Yes, the function is odd. So with the symmetric bounds $-1$ and $1$ the integral is $0$.